# JSF calendar Component

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, date, calendar

I need to add a popup calender using JSF. i am using netbeans 6.9.1 and galssfish 3.1.

I googled and found this

```
<ui:calendar binding="#{booking.calDate}" id="calDate" 
             dateFormatPattern="dd/MM/yyyy"   label="Date ::"/>
```

but it gives an error stating:

```
the component library facelets doesn't contain such component
```

What might be the correct way of making this work.

Secondly, the pattern the date will be stored or selected will appear in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` . I need to store this in the MySQL DB.

In the Bean Class should i say `Calendar cal = new Calendar();`?

Comment: Where did you copy the code. ui:calender is not a standard tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard JSF implementation doesn't ship with a popup calendar component, let alone Facelets. To confirm it for yourself, browse through all the JSF 2.0 and Facelets standard tags [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/).

You need to look for a 3rd party JSF component library, like [RichFaces](http://jboss.org/richfaces) which has a [`<rich:calendar>` component](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar), or [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) which has a [`<p:calendar>` component](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml), etcetera. All of them usually binds the value to a `java.util.Date` property.